# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'bind'

Tags: javascript

I had search through the net for the solutions. I had tried with 'on', 'click' but it does not works.

```
var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
        element.className = 'element';
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,127,127,' + ( Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.25 ) + ')';
        element.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        element.bind("click", function(e){ alert("testing"); });
```

From the code above it will display `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'bind'`. If i change the **bind** event to `element.click(function(){alert("testing")});` the code works fine but wont show the alert box when i clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a event listener you need o use [.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is used to pass a custom execution context to a function

```
element.addEventListener("click", function(e){ alert("testing"); });
```